# Should I consider this job offer rescinded?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, recruitment, human-resources

2 weeks ago during the Christmas/new year holidays, department head emailed me saying HR should send me the official offer sometime early in next month, but here is most of the information (salary, tentative start date, etc etc). Of course, i replied saying thank you and everything looks good and can't wait to start. But, now its been three weeks into the month, and nothing. I emailed the HR, but no reply. So, should I consider this "verbal offer" rescinded by now. Or wait for few more weeks, before accepting the defeat instead of the offer! It is a very large company with big HR by the way, and i won't be starting until summer, at the least.

Comment: You said you emailed HR, but have you emailed the department head? Or tried to reach out by phone to either HR or the department head?

Comment: Pick up the phone.  Call the department head.

Comment: is not even the 14th and u think we're three weeks into jan?

Comment: Contact the department had, as well.  For him, hiring is a huge pain in the butt that he wants to be over and dealt with.  For HR, it's just another folder on the desk.  The department head will push what needs to be pushed.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Given that OP was already given an offer, that post seems too different from this one, and those answers seem like some really bad advice for this situation.

Comment: Only after talking to someone and getting a definite no would I consider it rescinded.

Comment: I would have showed up in the starting date specified.

Answer (score 10):

**HR is not your friend** so don't act as if they are.  Nobody is sitting there and saying "Oh my!  We haven't called sdd!!!".  They are just operatives for the company.

Call them for a follow up.  This is too important to leave in email.  HR likely gets hundreds, if not **THOUSANDS** of emails every day.  Yours can get pushed down to the bottom, caught in a spam filter, of seen and forgotten.

**CALL THEM** or you might miss the opportunity

Comment: Yep, lots of reasons things might have fallen through.

Comment: I'd tone this down a shade, but agree that contacting the department head would be your best choice. Something like, "I wanted to check in as I've not heard anything ..."

Comment: @JimMeyer sure thing.  please feel free to add an answer of your own.

Comment: Some folks forget the obvious.  A **phone call** can work wonders where texting and emails fail.

Comment: @TheSharkKnight Your answer has the right elements, I'm just not well aligned with the strong opening of "HR is not your friend!" I agree that they're busy, and the response that's singular for the OP is one of hundreds for them.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely reach out to the company.

If the offer is still on the way and has been delayed, you reaching out and showing interest and investment in getting this position isn't going to change their mind about you and rescind the offer.

If they did decide to go another direction, then you know and you can continue looking.

It's the not knowing that is the worst part I would think.

Comment: How should the OP reach out how?

Answer (score 0):

Contact them and find out.   Ask them if there are any issues, as you were concerned that the offer has been lost in the post (maybe it has?)

Big companies can forget, 2 weeks can turn into 2 months, especially if you'd be starting in the summer.

Worst case scenario, at least your not left wandering what the situation is.

Comment: Contact them how?

Comment: Via telephone, since previous email was ignored.